# AngularJS Firebase login wrong password error handling

Tags: angularjs, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I want to show specific toaster error message if the password is wrong, this only when the email is verified. Can somebody suggest how to do this in my login controller?

```
app.controller("MyloginCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$location", "CommonProp",
    function ($scope, Auth, $location, CommonProp) {
        $scope.signIn = function () {
            var username = $scope.user.email;
            var password = $scope.user.password;
            Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .then(function (username) {
                    if (username.emailVerified) {
                        console.log("if condition", username.emailVerified);
                        $location.path('/app/dashboard');
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr["warning"]('Your email is NOT verified.', 'Verify email first!')
                        console.log("else condition", username.emailVerified);
                        console.log('Your email is NOT verified.', 'Verify email!');
                        $location.path('/login.signin');
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    toastr["warning"]('Your email is not registered in the database.', 'Register first!')
                    $scope.errMsg = true;
                    $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
                });
        }

    }]);
```

**Update**:

My goal is to check if email is verified, then:

- if not verified, toaster "email is not verified"
- if verified, check if password is correct
- if password correct, do the login and go to `location.path('/app.dashboard')`
- if password is wrong, toaster the message "password is wrong"
- if none of the above, then toaster "email is not registered"

Comment: Which part is giving you problems?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no part actually, when the password is incorrect, even if the email is verified, it jumps to the catch and shows the toaster message of email not registered.

Comment: Did you already step through the code and see what `username.emailVerified` is? For example does the property exist and is it indeed `false`? Or does `username.emailVerified` simply not exist?

Comment: if it is verified, i get a true and if not true, then the else part is fired, otherwise, the case is when it is true but the password is wrong, then the catch is fired and it says the email is not registered. Whereas, the catch should only be fired to say that the email is not registered at all.